# Prompt no internet connection for facebook sign in

Tags: android, facebook

I have just created my sample app that uses Facebook sign in feature(Just basic). Now what i want is, to make sure the internet connection is present. If no connection, i need to show proper information. So i would like to know if there is any exception handling or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
{
      Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
else
{
      Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

You have to give following permissions also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: No! No! I was not looking for that. I want to know if the facebook api has something for me...

Comment: Because the internet can be disconnected after the checking shows there is "Network Available"

Comment: By the way what does the last uses permission do?

Comment: @Nabin It allows applications to access information about networks

Comment: what about the first two comments that i did above ? :-) Would be grateful if you address those... Thank you

Comment: @Nabin I am not sure but as far as I know Facebook api doesn't provide something like that

Answer (score 0):

Just open a http connection to google. If it's successful you will know that it is present... `

URL checkforconnection = new URL("http://www.google.co.uk");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)checkforconnection.openConnection();

```
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200){

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();


        System.out.println("The link speed is " +wi.getLinkSpeed());
        System.out.println("All is well, we can proceed with the download");
        System.out.println("The mac address is " +wi.getMacAddress());

    }

    else{

        System.out.println("Something is wrong here");
    }`
```

You could just return something from the above piece of code and query it before you attempt your login.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear. My question is "What if the connection goes at the on going process, during sign in or after sign in..." So i want to keep tracking the connection without any kind of extra loop..??